# How to count points used in fitting regression line?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, gradient

I have extracted fundamental frequency values (f0) on 10 ms frames and I need to perform a regression analysis to get the gradient over an entire sentence and need to count the number of points used in fitting F0 regression line.

The code is below to get the gradient:

```
x = utt_frames_df['frameTime']
y = utt_frames_df['F0']
# Create a sequance of integers from 0 to x.size to use in np.polyfit() call
x_seq = np.arange(x.size) # should give you [ 0  1  2  3  4 ... 26]
# call numpy polyfit() method with x_seq, y 
fit = np.polyfit(x_seq, y, 1)
fit_fn = np.poly1d(fit)
utt_grad=fit[0]
```

Can anyone please help me in determining the number of points used in fitting the F0 regression line?

Comment: Is it not just x.size? or equivalently len(x)

Comment: yes equivalent to len(x)

Comment: But I'm saying that's the answer. The number of points used in the fit is len(x).